# Shall I write, I am going to buy or I have bought?

Tags: grammar, tense-agreement

I have just asked a new question about coconut oil in lifehack on stackexchange.
In the question, I said this

> I have not bought any coconut oil before...
>   I am wondering how it's possible for me to test if the coconut oil
>   **(options)** from a supermarket is poisonous?

The options between "I am going to buy" and "I have bought" have confused me.

Can you tell me which one of it is the better please?

Comment: Use *I am going to buy* as it states your intentions and time of action aptly.

Comment: "I have not bought coconut oil before." This means you have never purchased it. It *could* mean you've tried a sample or received it as a gift. I think you are trying to say, "I have not tried coconut oil before and I am wondering if there is a way to get a test sample before I commit to buying any. I have concerns about allergies/ quality control."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I have bought' tells us about something you've already done, in the past. 'I am going to buy' tells us about something you will do (or plan to do) in the future. The text you have shown above is correct.